# CSS Animation for a Vertical Line Going Upwards

Tags: css, gsap

i am trying to create a CSS Animation for a vertical line going upwards - the line should be within a specific div

I have used gsap - i have used as well ypercent field, however the line starts from below the FirstScene div while i need it to be contained within the FirstScene div

```js
gsap.fromTo(".vertical-line",{ yPercent:10 }, {yPercent:0,duration: 5});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.topnav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-size: x-large;
  background-color: black;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  float: right;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}

linkStyle {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li i {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#li-left {
  float: left;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.FirstScene {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.line {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width=10px;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.vertical-line {
  border-left: 6px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li id="li-left">
      <Link to="/" class="linkStyle"> MINA IBRAHIM
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://github.com/ibrahimmina">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/minasamyibrahim/">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="mailto: mina.ibrahim@aucegypt.edu">.email()</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/about" class="linkStyle"> .about()
      </Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<body>
  <section class="FirstScene">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="vertical-line">

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the bellow css for the Vertical Line Going Upwards animations

```
   .FirstScene{
  background-color: black;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
}

.vertical-line{
  border-left: 6px solid blue;
 animation-name: line;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
@keyframes line{
  0%{
    height: 0px;
  }
  100%{
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```